# Need to parse variable number of quoted values from a string

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to parse each quoted value for the '@name' keys in a string. The string can have a variable number of occurrences of this pair. I've tried a couple of things but they either get too bulky, so to speak, or they are beyond my knowledge level.

This is using Oracle SQL.

Any help is appreciated.

Here's a few examples:

/content/folder[@name='LocationB']/report[@name='Report29']

/content/folder[@name='LocationA']/folder[@name='Reports']/report[@name='ReportAAA']

/content/folder[@name='LocationA']/folder[@name='Reports']/folder[@name='FolderC']/folder[@name='FolderCD']/report[@name='ReportBBB']

/transientStateFolder/agentState[@name='2019-05-09T19:47:03.029Z']/reportView[@name='Report232']

CAMID("corp.xyz.net:u:254679b8195bf547a8b894de8a6ea822")/folder[@name='My Folders']/folder[@name='Subscriptions']/reportView[@name='My Daily Numbers']

I hope to end up with:

LocationB   Report29

LocationA   Reports    ReportAAA

LocationA   Reports    FolderC    FolderCD    ReportBBB

etc...

Comment: You could use [`regexp_instr`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_INSTR.html#GUID-D21B53A1-83E2-4722-9BBB-638470715DD6) to do pattern matching, but parsing is often better done by a programming language once, then insert the parsed data into the database for fast and easy querying. This is usually done as part of the data import, but it can be done after the fact.

Comment: True. It would be easy with a programming language.  In this case, we need direct sql to put into a report builder type of app and we don't have the liberty of executing outside apps that easily. dr's answer works perfectly for this situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have/know/want regexp - you can use SubStr() and InStr() functions:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select 1 "ID", '/content/folder[@name="LocationB"]/report[@name="Report29"]' "MY_STR" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ID", '/content/folder[@name="LocationA"]/folder[@name="Reports"]/report[@name="ReportAAA"]' "MY_STR" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "ID", '/content/folder[@name="LocationA"]/folder[@name="Reports"]/folder[@name="FolderC"]/folder[@name="FolderCD"]/report[@name="ReportBBB"]' "MY_STR" From Dual Union All
            Select 4 "ID", '/transientStateFolder/agentState[@name="2019-05-09T19:47:03.029Z"]/reportView[@name="Report232"]' "MY_STR" From Dual Union All
            Select 5 "ID", 'CAMID("corp.xyz.net:u:254679b8195bf547a8b894de8a6ea822")/folder[@name="My Folders"]/folder[@name="Subscriptions"]/reportView[@name="My Daily Numbers"]' "MY_STR" From Dual
        )
            
        
Select
    ID "ID",
    RTRIM(
          SubStr(MY_STR, InStr(MY_STR, '[@name="', 1, 1) + 8, InStr(MY_STR, '"]', 1, 1) - InStr(MY_STR, '[@name="', 1, 1) - 8) || ' ' || 
          SubStr(MY_STR, InStr(MY_STR, '[@name="', 1, 2) + 8, InStr(MY_STR, '"]', 1, 2) - InStr(MY_STR, '[@name="', 1, 2) - 8) || ' ' ||
          SubStr(MY_STR, InStr(MY_STR, '[@name="', 1, 3) + 8, InStr(MY_STR, '"]', 1, 3) - InStr(MY_STR, '[@name="', 1, 3) - 8) || ' ' ||
          SubStr(MY_STR, InStr(MY_STR, '[@name="', 1, 4) + 8, InStr(MY_STR, '"]', 1, 4) - InStr(MY_STR, '[@name="', 1, 4) - 8) || ' ' ||
          SubStr(MY_STR, InStr(MY_STR, '[@name="', 1, 5) + 8, InStr(MY_STR, '"]', 1, 5) - InStr(MY_STR, '[@name="', 1, 5) - 8)
         ) "MY_STR"
From
    tbl
```

... resulting as ...

| ID | MY_STR |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | LocationB Report29 |
| 2 | LocationA Reports ReportAAA |
| 3 | LocationA Reports FolderC FolderCD ReportBBB |
| 4 | 2019-05-09T19:47:03.029Z Report232 |
| 5 | My Folders Subscriptions My Daily Numbers |

Regards...